# Bluetooth power standard values

Tags: power, rf, communication, bluetooth, radio

Let´s say I have a device with a bluetooth (BLE) 5.1 radio and I would like to know when, using a mobile phone, the power received from the device is good enough to stablish a reliable communication or I need to place it in another localization.

Is there a standard power value so I can decide wether to rate the connectivity as bad or good?
The radio of each mobile phone will be different so maybe there´s no standard, and this is what confuses me...how companies do this connection quality test?

Nonethless, maybe there´s a value at which any bluetooth radio of any phone would stablish a reliable communication.

Comment: Look up Friis Loss

Comment: Assuming you mean RSSI, then higher power gives higher probability of successful transmission, but it cannot be used to measure the quality of the link. In order to do that, you need to take the receiver's characteristics in account: sensitivity, blocking, adjacent channel rejection, image rejection and so on. You have to measure the number of successfully vs unsuccessfully received packages over time, that's the only way.

Answer (score 0):

You need special software, tool, etc to operate your Bluetooth device however you want. Usually, these required components are supplied by the manufacturer of the chip used in the Bluetooth device. By the help of software, you can easily change the rf output power.

To measure connection quality, you need a companion device that communicates with your Bluetooth device and makes you enable to see PER (Packet Error Rate), BER (Bit Error Ratio) or BLER (Block Error Ratio).

If you have all of them, just measure the connection quality by using different Rf outpower levels and decide the minimum RFoutpower level to communicate well.

Please don't forget companion device is generally called as communication tester.